# Where to check the logs for postStart and preStop hook command output?

Tags: kubernetes, containers

We run CLI from postStart hook like

```
lifecycle:
      postStart:
        exec:
          command:
          - /bin/bash
          - -c
          - some CLI
```

The CLI is not just simple `echo` and will call backend API (which has logs). So curious how to debug if the CLI works? Where can we find the logs for this CLI and API?

Answer (score 1):

As per this [official doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-lifecycle-hooks/#debugging-hook-handlers) , Hook handler logs are not exposed in pods but you can generate the events if the hook handler fails as described in the official documentation by running the

```
kubectl describe pod <pod_name>
```

Based on the hook handler failure logs we can decide whether it is working or not.

To check the backend API logs make sure where this API is directed to and where the logs are stored.
**For example :** If the backend API logs are storing in container you can check the logs using below command :

```
kubectl logs <pod_name> -c <container-name>
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation on [Container Lifecycle Hooks](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-lifecycle-hooks/#debugging-hook-handlers):

> The logs for a Hook handler are not exposed in Pod events.

As a workaround, if your `postStart` output can be redirected to a file, you can copy the example from the K8s documentation (https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/attach-handler-lifecycle-event/) where it uses [redirection](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html).

For example, I have a `postStart` hook that runs a script and redirects all `stderr` output to a log:

```yaml
lifecycle:
  postStart:
    exec:
      command:
        - /bin/sh
        - -c
        - python /usr/local/app/scripts/myscript.py 2> /usr/local/app/logs/myscript.log
```

And then later, I can just read log from the pod:

```
$ k exec pod/mypod -- cat /usr/local/app/logs/myscript.log
```

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, to debug the CLI command in you Kubernetes `postStart` hook, I will modify the command to log its output to a file within the container, e.g., `some CLI > /path/to/logfile 2>&1`.

This log can be accessed by entering the container (`kubectl exec -it <pod-name> -- /bin/bash`) and viewing the file (`cat /path/to/logfile`).

I will also use `kubectl describe pod <pod-name>` to see related events, including `postStart` hook execution.

Also, since your CLI calls a backend API, I will check the backend's logs for relevant request data or errors.